# Get sector_t value to write to disk

Tags: memory-management, io, kernel

How to get the sector value i.e sector_t for bio->bi_sector to make a bio submit I/O call to a block device? I have inode, page index and page. I need to find a suitable sector value to the block device to complete the I/O of writing a page to device.

Thanks!